# Modulo calculation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I am stuck on this modulo calculation:
$$718^{143} \pmod{1260}$$

I have tried using the Euler totient function with no success ($\phi(1260) = 288)$. I think I could solve it using the Chinese remainder theorem but I am guessing there is a faster way.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: I expect the most standard way to do this is exponentiation by squaring. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring But there might be a neat trick in this particular case.

Comment: Using Carmichael function might be very helpful... For your case, this states that $$a^{\lambda (1260)}=a^{12}\equiv 1 \mod 1260 \;\; \forall a, n\in \mathbb N : \text{gcd}(a,n)=1$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:** $718=2\cdot 359$, $\ 1260=2\cdot 630$, $\ \varphi(630)=144$,
So, $359^{143}\equiv 359^{-1}\pmod{630}$ which can be found using the Euclidean algorithm, say it's $x$.

We also need to calculate $2^{142}\pmod{630}$, say it's $y$, and then we can combine them to
$$718^{143}=2\cdot 2^{142}\cdot 359^{143}\equiv 2xy\pmod{2\cdot 630}$$
using that $a\equiv b\pmod m\implies 2a\equiv 2b\pmod{2m}$.

Comment: Why do people feel completely justified in using a calculator to multiply two large numbers but still want to do this Mod problems by hand?  It is straightforward on a computer:  $1192$.  Done.